# Covariance of TimeSeries in v10.0-10.3

Tags: probability-or-statistics, time-series

The following works in v11.2-12.0:

```
ts1 = TimeSeries[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}}];
ts2 = TimeSeries[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}];
Covariance[ts1, ts2]
(* -1/3 *)
```

but fails in v10.0-10.3 with message:

> Covariance::vctmat: The arguments to Covariance are not a pair of vectors or a pair of matrices of equal length.

Same problem occurs for `TemporalData`.  However `Variance` and `Mean` both work in all of these versions:

```
Variance[ts1]
(* 1/3 *)

Mean[ts1]
(* 1/2 *)
```

Bug? Workaround?

Comment: a work-around: `Covariance[ts1["Values"], ts2["Values"]]` (same for `TemporalData`)?

Comment: It looks to me that this functionality was released in 10.4 (so not a bug)